# Is LibreOffice's SimpleCommandMail handling of commas for Title, Body and Attachment buggy?

Tags: libreoffice-basic

(I am new at stackoverflow, I apologize if I fail to meet established styling conventions). In LibreOffice Basic it is possible to construct a mail to be sent with the default system mail client. This is done with SimpleMailClient, here is a generic example:

```
eMailer = createUnoService("com.sun.star.system.SimpleCommandMail")
eMailClient = eMailer.querySimpleMailClient() 
eMessage = eMailClient.createSimpleMailMessage()
eMessage.setRecipient("someone@mail.com,somebody@mail.com")
eMessage.setSubject("Some subject") 'no commas in subject!
eMessage.body = "Some Text" 'no commas in body!
eMessage.setAttachement(array(file1, file2)) 'no commas in file names!
eMailClient.sendSimpleMailMessage(eMessage, 0)
```

This works fine, the user is presented with a mail in his default mail client and then just needs to press "send" to get it out.

But if there is a comma in the title, the title gets cut at the comma, same for body, and for attachments the files are split into separate entries which then of course fail. (For example: File "Hello, world.docx" will be split into "Hello" and "world.docx" and of course none of these two would exist, which will lead to a cascade of error messages from the system mail client).

I am thinking about reporting a bug to LibreOffice, but before I do so I want to ask here if this behaviour is expected and if there is a workaround or some formatting in the construction of the respective strings which I am missing (For example: enclosing the strings with quotation marks, or so).

I need to add that this behaviour (splitting at commas) is valid and desirable for setRecipient() where it is used to send a mail to several recipients. But this behaviour seems to have been extended to title, body, attachment, and that doesn't make any sense with these mail-elements IMO.

I've done intensive internet research on the topic, consulted the LibreOffice API and had a lengthy discussion on the matter with ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

The LibreOffice issue is tracked in [bug report 125950](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125950), and the root cause is tracked in Thunderbird issues [258887](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=258887) and [900117](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=900117). Ideally, the problem would be resolved on Thunderbird's side.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. Kind regards, Mike